# Using Linq .Min() to get Min Date

Tags: c#, .net, collections

i'm trying to get min date from a collection

```
someCollection.Min(d => d.Dates.Select(c => c.ReservationDateStart)).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it returns exception

> At least one object must implement IComparable

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117231/using-linq-min-at-least-one-object-must-implement-icomparable) i came up with that Min didn't work but how we get min object from collection based on it's property collection of min?

my collection is something like this

```
public class InfoDatesViewModel
    {
        public DateTime OccureFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime OccureTo { get; set; }
        public string RecurreFrom { get; set; }
        public string RecurreTo { get; set; }
        public int RecurrentType { get; set; }
        public bool IsFullDay { get; set; }
        public int ReservedQuantity { get; set; }
        public ReservedDateViewModel[] Dates { get; set; }
    }
```

and `ReservedDateViewModel` is

```
public class ReservedDateViewModel
    {
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReservationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReservationDateEnd { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReservationDateStart { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And what does `ReservedDateViewModel` look like?

Comment: Are you trying to find the min `ReservationDateStart` in a collection of `InfoDatesViewModel` or you just want to find the min in one instance of `InfoDatesViewModel`

Comment: thanks Corak sachin...  @KooKiz answer is acceptable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `InfoDatesViewModel.Dates` is a collection, so you can't compare it directly.

When having a collection of collections, you can flatten them using the `SelectMany` operator:

```
someCollection.SelectMany(c => c.Dates).Min(d => d.ReservationDateStart);
```